# Export or Report Related Products in Magento?

Tags: magento

Was wondering if this is possible either by running a report or an export profile? Basically all of my stores products have 4 selected (not rule based) related products. Looking to get a generate a CSV of that information to do some auditing. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think your best chance is running a RAW query against the database. You have all the relations in the catalog_product_link table and all product information in the catalog_product_entity table:

```
SELECT cpe1.sku, cpe2.sku FROM catalog_product_link cpl INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity cpe1 ON (cpe1.entity_id = cpl.product_id) INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity cpe2 ON (cpe2.entity_id = cpl.linked_product_id)
```